# Animating jQuery Masonry elements one axis at a time

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

I have a jQuery Masonry layout that I am initialising like so:

```
$("#container").masonry({
    itemSelector: ".pod, .smallpod",
    animationOptions: {
        queue: true
    }
});
```

I thought that the `queue` option would queue the animation so that it animates `x` first, then `y` afterwards. Turns out that isn't right.

Does anyone know if this is possible? I've had a look through the Unminified jQuery Masonry JS but I can't find the bit to change.

Library Link: http://masonry.desandro.com/masonry.pkgd.js

I've found the `moveTo()` and the `transitionTo()` functions, but I'm not sure what to change.

Within the `translate()` function there is:

```
function( x, y ) {
    return 'translate3d(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px, 0)';
} :
function( x, y ) {
    return 'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';
};
```

But, I can't find a way to just animate it an axis at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out you **can** do this in CSS3 - So, I'm answering my own question..

1) Set `transitionDuration` to `0`

2) Added transition property `left, top, opacity`

Comment: I've lost 50rep because I offered a bounty and figured it out myself?! Seriously SO - that's poor...

Answer (score 0):

First off, you can check both axis independently. There's the variable didnotmoved that is equal to both axis. Create a 2nd variable and then make 2 if-statement to increment or decrement the x or y axis.

Comment: Simply saying make 1 variable into 2 variables doesn't constitute an answer, especially when in the context of jQuery Masonry (a lot of code). Sorry... In short, this answer wasn't actually helpful. Happy to vote you up if you edit for more detail :/